# Why is "his" used instead of "him" in this U. Sinclair quote?

Tags: word-usage, quotations

> It is difficult to get a man to understand something, when his salary depends upon his not understanding it
> -- *Upton Sinclair*

Why *"... **his** not understanding it"*, and not *"... **him** not understanding it"*?

I thought that the meaning was *"... when his salary depends about (the man) not understanding (something)"*

Comment: If you google **possessives genitives before gerunds** you will find numerous explanations of these constructions

Comment: @RonaldSole: thanks for the pointer. https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/possessive-case-gerunds/ was very clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comprehension is correct. Here "his" is used because "the man not understanding something" is considered as an "attribute" of the man.